# React Native + Appium iOS elementByAccesibilityId.text()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, appium, jestjs, e2e-testing

I'm writing tests for React Native using Appium + Jest for both Android and iOS.

Here's my React Native element:

```
<Text accessibilityLabel={'emailError'}>Invalid email</Text>
```

Here's the Promise chain I created to extract the value of a React Native `Text` element:

```
driver.elementByAccessibilityId('emailError')
      .then(error => error.text())
      .then(errorText => expect(errorText).toBe('Invalid email'))
```

On Android, this test passes. On iOS, this test fails, and `errorText === 'emailError'`.

Why is this, and is there a solution that works cross-platform for extracting text?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Using `testID` instead of `accessibilityLabel` worked for me on iOS. For Android, `accessible: true` and `accessibilityLabel` should do the trick. But: You can't just set them all. If `accessibilityLabel` and `testID` are both set, it won't work on iOS anymore.

Example for iOS:

```js
<Text testID={'emailError'}>Invalid email</Text>
```

Example for Android:

```js
<Text accessible={true} accessibilityLabel={'emailError'}>Invalid email</Text>
```

A library (or just create your own function) like https://github.com/tipsi/react-native-testid can help you with setting the correct attributes based on the platform.

Comment: Thanks man. it's help for me. the important to note here is "If accessibilityLabel and testID are both set, it won't work on iOS anymore.". My case I am giving both and it's not working in iOS.

Comment: This is working for me in 0.64.0. I'm using a utility function using Platform.select to add specific ones for specific OSes. Something like: `Platform.select({android: {accessible: true, accessibilityLabel: id}, ios: {testID: id}})`

Comment: Hack with `accessibilityLabel` instead of `testID` on Android is not actual since `react-native@0.65.x` !!!

See changelog: https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#android-specific-9 ;

Commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/381fb395ad9d2d48717a5d082aaedbecdd804554 ;