# React Native + Appium iOS TextInput.clear()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, appium

Here's my code for clearing an input on Android with Appium in React Native:

```js
driver.elementByAccessibilityId(inputName)
      .then(input => input.click()
      .then(() => input.clear()))
```

The `input.click()` exists because `input.clear()` doesn't seem to select the text field in Android; this workaround works well on Android.

However, `input.click()` doesn't seem to do anything on iOS. Is there a workaround that anyone has found for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my workaround: Send as many backspaces as there were characters in the `TextInput`.

You'd have to know what text was in the `TextInput`, unfortunately, due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642256/react-native-appium-ios-elementbyaccesibilityid-text). Here's my full code if anyone would like to use it:

```
    import {Platform} from 'react-native';

    /**
     * @param {string} inputName Name of element
     * @param {string} value Value previously in the input, used by iOS.
     * @returns {() => Promise}
     */
    function clearInput(inputName, value) {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            return () => driver.elementByAccessibilityId(inputName)
                .then(input => input.click()
                .then(() => input.clear()))
                .then(() => driver.hideDeviceKeyboard());
        }
        else {
            return () => driver.elementByAccessibilityId(inputName)
                .then(input => input.type('\b'.repeat(value.length)))
                .then(() => driver.hideDeviceKeyboard());
        }
    }
```

I'd still like to know if there's some way you're supposed to do it in iOS though, or if this is just a bug with Appium.